# how do i take previously calculated x and y values and place them into g.drawLine parameters

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to create a program that takes a user-inputted string in y=mx+b form and uses that inputted equation to graph a line. The only thing I don't have down pat is this single issue: how can I take the calculated x and y values and place them in the g.drawLine parameters?

```
    public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawLine(x,y,x2,y2);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
}
```

Comment: whats wrong? Everything should work.

Comment: @M.M. the asker means that mean x, y and so on are defined in another method. They want to know how to pass information to the paint method.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a Line class that has instance variables for m, b, etc, and have its paint or display method draw a line using those variables. Then, make a Line object from that class and call its paint method inside that one (passing the graphics object as a parameter). This would have the added advantage that if you ever wanted to draw more than one line, you could just make more than one Line object and call each of their paint methods.

Something like, in main:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    myLine.paint(g);
    ...
```

... and in the Line class:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawLine(myx1, myy1, myx2, myy2);
    ....
```

---

EDIT: If you want a really quick solution and don't need to make the program extendible, you could also store the line's properties as [static variables](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-static-variable-methods.html) of the main class. That would look like:

```
class Main {
    static int lineInformation;

    void userInputMethod() {
        lineInformation = ... // the user input
        ...
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(lineInformation,...);
        ...
    }
}
```

Again, though, I would definitely recommend a Line class for a program you will later use or modify.

Comment: the problem with the static variables quick-fix is that I have user-inputted info that I turned into the first and last point of the line being graphed. I need to take these points and put them in their corresponding place in the parameters of g.drawLine(); Static variables wouldn't work because my values cannot be constants, and so their values would not carry over through each method, only the variable itself. Catch my drift?

Comment: Maybe I don't. Static variables *can* be modified, it's just bad practice. They act like local variables except that they are visible and accessible (including modifiable) in all methods of the class rather than just one.

Comment: I edited it just so we're all on the same page. Did I misunderstand your requirements?

Comment: All good. Welcome to SO. Feel free to give somebody an answer tick if one of the responses helped you.

Answer (score 0):

A rough list of what to do

1. Extract m and b from the String.
2. plug in 0 for x and use that (x,y) pair for the first point
3. plug in the width for x and use that result for the second point
4. You need to take `-y + height` if you want it to be graphed with y growing as we move up

Answer (score 0):

This will make sure the line fills the area of the component:

```
double m= ...
double b= ...
double x=g.getClipBounds().x;
double x2=g.getClipBounds().x+g.getClipBounds().width;
g.drawLine(x,m*x+b,x2,m*x2+b);
```